# chart.Correlation with many inputs

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I'm trying to plot a correlation matrix with many inputs.

My problem is that the correlation coefficient have the same fixed size as the correlation plots.

I'm guessing there are two solutions :

-separate the plots from the coefficients

-try to scale the plots in a different way than the coefficients.

I must admit I don't fully understand the inner workings of the function.

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you want. Do you want smaller data point in the lower corner?

Comment: I' d like to have a better view of the correlation plots. It's the numbers I don't really care about.

Comment: You cannot get bigger plots when you remove the numbers. Make the points smaller, output to pdf, then you can scale arbitrarily.

Comment: I'm actually using Rexcel, so I don't want to output it to pdf. I'm gonna try to make the points smaller.

Comment: Have you considered the `pairs.panels {Psych}` function? You have a few options there to tweak the graph. But still won't have full control.